# Columns on rows stacking. Expected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a very basic question about the fluid grid layout on bootstrap 3.  Basically I have a single row inside of a container.  I've tried 10:2 11:1 ratios and experience the same problem.  My syntax for the layout is this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-11 column">
      <h3 align="right">Here is a longer string.</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 column">
      <h3 align="right">Shorter.<h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is this; when I reduce the window size, and not by very much, these two columns stack on top of one another.  It it the normal behavior of bootstrap for columns to stack upon one another in this way?  I thought that since they are in the same row that the text should wrap and the columns should stay next to one another because they are in the same row.  Am I wrong/crazy?  I appreciate you taking the time to help me.

Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you are describing is intended. It is an example of Bootstrap's responsiveness, whereby the appearance of the page changes according to the size of the viewport. You can read more about this [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). In particular, check out these breakpoints:

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

So when you use "col-md-*" what happens is that if the viewport is 992px or greater, the column will be displayed normally (i.e. side-by-side, next to the other columns). If you shrink the browser window, or open the page in a smaller device, it will be displayed in a stacked format.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me.  This was the kicker "Don't want your columns to simply stack in smaller devices? Use the extra small and medium device grid classes by adding .col-xs-* .col-md-*".